# PHP Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. Cake Version 4, Php version 7.4

Tags: php, cakephp, ini, intl

Windows User here.  I have enabled the extension in php.ini.  I restarted my apache server and I still get the error.  I still get the same error when I try to use cake commands.

I've tried installing different versions of php.  I've tried renaming the php (development ini) to php.ini and then editing it.

I just don't understand where I am wrong. Anyone have any suggestions or know of a good tutorial that will guide me? [image]

Comment: Have you tried looking at the output of `phpinfo()` in a web page, to see exactly what your server thinks is running (version, ini files, loaded modules, etc.)? And running `php -i` on the command line to see if it differs?

Comment: There are often two different php.ini files, one for web and one for CLI. Make sure here to also adjust the latter as the error seems to indicate you only changed one of them.